# Can I be charged for tap water in a restaurant in New Mexico, USA

Tags: united-states, water, restaurants, new-mexico

Recently I was eating at a rather upscale steak restaurant in Santa Fe, New Mexico, and at the start of the service the waiter asked if I wanted bottled or tap water.  I opted for tap water, and was provided with it (and refilled various times during the meal).  At the end of the evening the bill included a line item of $11 for water.  I didn't object as I didn't know the laws on the subject.  I've since done some quick googling and can't easily find an answer (I'm probably just blind and/or using the wrong terms).  FWIW the cost of the water amounted to slightly over 7% of the total bill - after tax!

Can I be charged for tap water at a restaurant in New Mexico?

Comment: Probably the menu said something about this...?

Comment: It is possible for the restaurant to charge you, so yes.